# "pip list" error 124 - Installing on Mac OS x

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, pip

I'm trying to install pip. I'm running into a problem and I'm not sure how to get around it.

I have activated my virtualenv.

When I run $ pip I get the list of commands, but when I run $ pip list I get the following response.

```
distribute (0.6.28)
pip (1.4.1)
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Marcus/Documents/Django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 134, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/Marcus/Documents/Django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pip/commands/list.py", line 80, in run
    self.run_listing(options)
  File "/Users/Marcus/Documents/Django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pip/commands/list.py", line 127, in run_listing
    self.output_package_listing(installed_packages)
  File "/Users/Marcus/Documents/Django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/list.py", line 136, in output_package_listing
    if dist_is_editable(dist):
  File "/Users/Marcus/Documents/Django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 347, in dist_is_editable
    req = FrozenRequirement.from_dist(dist, [])
  File "/Users/Marcus/Documents/Django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 194, in from_dist
    assert len(specs) == 1 and specs[0][0] == '=='
AssertionError

Storing complete log in /Users/Marcus/.pip/pip.log
```

THanks

Comment: The ultimate problem is that this is too old a version of distribute for pip 1.4. And in fact, _every_ version of distribute is too old; the package was merged back into `setuptools`, and `distribute 0.7` is really just a shim that pulls in a requirement on `setuptools`… If you can explain how you installed them, it will be easier to explain how to fix it. Or, more simply, just start over and install `setuptools` and `pip` and/or `virtualenv` from scratch, and don't touch `distribute` at all, and you'll be set.

Comment: I wish I could trace back all my steps that I took to install the packages. How do I start over? Is there a way to delete what I already have installed or do I need to just reinstall over the previous copies

Comment: Well… are you using Apple's Python, or have you installed a third-party Python (or a Django binary distribution that includes its own Python) and used that instead of Apple's?

Comment: Also, it's worth checking whether this error happens outside the virtualenv or just inside. If it only happens inside, you can probably just create a new venv to start over… but you probably want to fix things globally anyway.

Comment: Anyway, have you tried to solution AirThomas suggested? If you use pip to upgrade distribute and pip, that should automatically pull in an up-to-date setuptools and replace distribute with the setuptools stub and everything should just work. (Maybe cross your fingers while testing.)

Comment: I've tried all of these tips, but nothing has worked. I'm still stuck at the same error. What I did: reinstall pip, setup tools, virtualenv, python. but I'm still in the same errors

Comment: Can you post the information after all those reinstalls—in particular, which versions of pip and setuptools, and, if you have it, distribute?

Answer (score 1):

Try the solution suggested [here on GitHub](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1093):

> It happens when you install distribute using
>   http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py script. Running pip
>   install -U distribute fixes the problem. The bug reproduces only in
>   pip==1.4.

Comment: No luck this this approach